# Spring AOP bring exception after transaction rollback

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

I just play with code and try to understand how the transaction and rollback work in spring (I am using spring-boot and spring-dao). However during my expirements I was faced with exception which cannot be explain by me. 
So I have a controller

```
@RestController
public class OrderController {

@Autowired
CarSvc carSvc;

@Autowired
OrderService orderSvc;

@RequestMapping(value="/administrator/order/{id}", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public Message closeOrder(@PathVariable Long id){
    orderSvc.closeOrder(id);
    return new Massage("test");
}
```

}

This controller call this service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class OrderSvc extends AbstractService implements OrderService {

public void closeOrder(Long id) {
    final Order order = getDAO().findOne(id);
    Boolean isUserCanCloseOrder = order.getCarWashId().equals(getCarWashIdForAdmin());
    if(isUserCanCloseOrder){
        final Iterable<Order> all = getDAO().findAll();
        for(Order o : all){
            try {
                orderRepo.closeOrder(o);
            }catch (Exception e){
                System.out.printf("error id=" + o.getId() + " , message : " + e.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }else {
        throw new AuthorizationException("User is not allowed to close order with id = " + id);
    }
}
```

}

And this service in try block calls the following repository

```
@Repository
public class OrderRepo implements OrderRepository {

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void closeOrder(Order order) {
    if(order.getClose() != null){
        order.setUpdateVersion(77);
    }else{
        order.setCarWashId(1000L + order.getId());
    }
    final List<OrderedService> services = order.getServices();
    for(OrderedService s: services){
        s.setUpdateVersion(77);
        orderedServiceDAO.save(s);
    }
    orderDAO.save(order);
}
```

}

The logic is following: for part of `order` in repository I just set update  version (I need to understand is db was updated ) and for the rest I `setCarWashId` with not valid value to invoke sql exception and see is rollback work fine (sql exception due to foreign key constraint fails).

At the begging the application works fine and moves through the all orders  and show me `System.out.printf` from the service with all my bad orders. But then when the loop was finished, the application failed with the following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`pitstop`.`orders`, CONSTRAINT `order_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`car_wash_id`) REFERENCES `carwash` (`id`))
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:932) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar:5.1.38]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3281) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:159) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:351) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1258) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.closeOrder(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at biz.controllers.rest.administrator.OrderController.closeOrder(OrderController.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

I understand the exception due to incorrect FK but why it appear? I have catch block for exception. And why in log was mentioned only my controller (`biz.controllers.rest.administrator.OrderController.closeOrder`) and there is not link to services or repository?

Please explain me, what is going on. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the reason but the exception appeared due to `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` in class `OrderSvc`. When this annotation was deleted the problem disappeared

Answer (score 0):

> I understand the exception due to incorrect FK but why it appear? I have catch block for exception.

As soon as an exception appears ***anywhere*** in the processing chain, spring's transaction manager "marks the transaction for rollback". Even if you have a catch block at the outer calling layers of your processing chain (like you have it in the controller) the request will fail and the the overall transaction will be rolled back. By specifying `rollbackFor = Exception.class` in your OrderRepo's `@Transaction`  definition, you are asking Spring to roll back *entire transaction* if any exception occurs. Somewhat similar issue is discussed [here on spring forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/5775-transaction-propagation-and-exception-rollback).

Additionally, based on your stack trace, if you look at Spring's transaction processing code around line 761 in `org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)` you will be able to understand what is happening internally. Put a breakpoint there and understand the conditions under which Spring is processing the transaction and throwing/handling/logging exceptions. This is how I often understand what Spring transaction management is trying to do.

> And why in log was mentioned only my controller (biz.controllers.rest.administrator.OrderController.closeOrder) and there is not link to services or repository?

`at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.closeOrder(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]`

This line in your stack trace does represent the call to the OrderService (via proxy). Usually you should see the actual class in the stack trace further up at some point where the proxy invoker resolves and calls the actual class. Are you sure you have provided the full stack trace here? Did you remove some lines? Was there any other stack trace in log or just this one?